# how export html code in js file for use it jquery script?

Tags: jquery

I have this html code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ... // call jquery etc // 
    <script src="dialog.js"></script>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
      openmydialog(); // open dialog defined with jquery in dialog.js //
    </script>
  </head>   
  <body>
    ...
    <div id="my-div"> Text </div>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

well, all work correctly. I have only a problem. How I can export the:

```
<div id="my-div"> Text </div>
```

in dialog.js and to do that work correctly?
I have tried defining a variable, writing something like:

```
var myvar = '<div id="my-div"> Text </div>';
$("#my-div").html(myvar);
```

but did not worked. I have tried too with `document.write` but same. Any solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

You were close, if you're starting with HTML...

```
var myvar = '<div id="my-div"> Text </div>';
```

...you need to *parse* it and then add it to the page somewhere

```
    $(myvar).appendTo(document.body);
//  ^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//  Parse it   add it   somewhere
```

`appendTo` is just one of the many ways you can add it to the page; more on that (and jQuery in general, including how you parse snippets of HTML) [in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com).